# Connecting ADSL Modem cum Wi-Fi Router which is 802.11g to a Wi-Fi only Router 802.11n

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, soho

I would like to upgrade my network from 802.11g to 802.11n. The current modem I have is an ADSL model with Wi-Fi router built in. I would want to use the modem but not the built-in 802.11g AP. Instead I want to connect to another router with 802.11n and have a faster connection to stream movies.

Comment: This does not really seem like a question?

Comment: For this question to be more useful and answerable, we should have more details of the modem/router hardware and your client devices.  What's the make/model of your modem and WiFi router?  How many Ethernet ports does each have?  How many clients will be needing to make a wired connection?  How many wireless?  What are the capabilities of the wireless clients?  802.11a/b/g/n?  2.4 or 5 GHz, or both?

Comment: Clients aside, you should just be able to disable the wireless radio on the adsl modem/wifi router combo and then disable DHCP on the new wifi router so it is used only as an access point. This will make it so you don't have to make any major configuration changes on your network.

Answer (score -1):

1. Look up the make & model of the modem/router.
2. Go to the vendor's website and download the manual.
3. Log into the modem/router by typing its IP (the default gateway IP) into your browser and using the default username/password listed in the manual.
4. Refer to the manual on how to put the modem/router in bridge mode.
5. Connect your dedicated wireless router to the modem using an ethernet cable.

Comment: This method would cause him to have to redo any port forwards, static IPs or any other router configs. Why not keep the router and just add an access point?

Comment: @MaQleod: I assumed that he wanted to use the new wireless N router as his actual router, not just add wireless N capabilities to his network and stick with built-in router of the modem. But that's just what I'd do in the same situation, since my router configurations aren't that much work to migrate to a new router, and having a G and N router running in the same space can cause interference problems. But adding the new router as an AP will work too.

Comment: g and n can run together fine with out interference. n routers by default have g enabled. A second access point that is g is not going to cause problems. I have that exact setup in my home and I can stream video on two phones and a vizio device on g and an iPad and laptop on n and have no conflicts or slow downs. All that matters is that only one manages DHCP. Even if you don't want both active, you can just disable the wireless on the g router and it will still be a router, it just won't have an active wireless radio. Config saved, N access point enabled, very very easy setup.

Comment: Sorry but that's really poor logic. Even 2 wireless G routers/APs can cause interference with one another, so just because wireless N routers also support wireless G doesn't mean having another device broadcasting on the same or partially overlapping channels won't cause interference. Likewise, there's no rule that if you can stream video that means no interference is occurring. If you want to use your modem's built-in router yourself, that's fine. But there's nothing wrong with using a dedicate wireless router and simply using the modem as a bridge.

Comment: You can set to different channels. You can also use different frequencies. You can strategically place them. There are many ways to keep access points from interfering.

Comment: Thanks @MaQleod and Lèse majesté for providing a solution. Let me try both the options and check how it works in my home setup. Thanks once again.

Comment: @MacQleod: I never said there weren't ways to avoid interference. I simply stated that it _could_ cause interference, which it clearly can. The idea that wireless N routers having G capabilities means wireless N & G routers can't cause cross interference is ludicrous. But I'm tired of your trolling...